# Python - Organizar listas de listas, com base no índice[0] das listas filho

Tags: python, lista

Estou com dificultade em organizar essa lista de listas:

```
data = [['Antônio', '01/01/2020', 'Faltou'],
['Antônio', '15/01/2020', 'Faltou'],
['Antônio', '20/01/2020', 'Remarcou'],
['Pedro', '02/02/2020', 'Faltou'],
['Zeca', '10/11/2021', 'Compareceu'],
['Zeca', '15/11/2021', 'Faltou']]

x, y, i = 0, 0, 0
lista1 = []
a = data[x][0]
b = data[y][0]
for lista in data:
    if a == data[y][0]:
        y = y + 1
        i = i + 1
y = 1
lista1.extend(data[x])
while y < i:
    lista1.append(data[y][1])
    lista1.append(data[y][2])
    y = y + 1
print(lista1)
```

RESULTADO QUE EU TENHO:

```
lista1 = ['Antônio', '01/01/2020', 'Faltou', '15/01/2020', 'Faltou', '20/01/2020', 'Remarcou']
```

RESULTADO QUE QUERO CHEGAR:

```
lista1 = [['Antônio', '01/01/2020', 'Faltou', '15/01/2020', 'Faltou', '20/01/2020', 'Remarcou'],['Pedro', '02/02/2020', 'Faltou'],['Zeca', '10/11/2021', 'Compareceu', '15/11/2021', 'Faltou']]
```

Como faço para continuar interando nas linhas de baixo e repetindo a mesma lógica?

Answer (score 2):

Embora seja possível fazer o que você quer, não acho que essa estrutura (uma lista de listas) seja a melhor opção (mais sobre isso no final).

Enfim, para obter a estrutura que você quer, uma solução seria:

```py
data = [
    ['Antônio', '01/01/2020', 'Faltou'],
    ['Antônio', '15/01/2020', 'Faltou'],
    ['Antônio', '20/01/2020', 'Remarcou'],
    ['Pedro', '02/02/2020', 'Faltou'],
    ['Zeca', '10/11/2021', 'Compareceu'],
    ['Zeca', '15/11/2021', 'Faltou']
]

resultado = {}
for nome, dt, acao in data:
    resultado.setdefault(nome, [nome]).extend([dt, acao])
resultado = list(resultado.values())
print(resultado)
```

Ou seja, primeiro eu crio um dicionário cujas chaves são os nomes, e os valores são as respectivas listas contendo as datas e ações. Ao final, crio uma lista com os valores.

Fiz isso porque é uma solução que escala muito melhor do que o código proposto na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/580528/112052). Não que esteja  errado, afinal ele serve muito bem para listas pequenas. Mas para listas maiores já começa a dar problema.

Isso porque, a cada iteração, ele cria uma lista com os nomes encontrados até então, e depois verifica se o nome atual está nesta lista. Caso esteja, faz outro loop pelos nomes até encontrar a lista correta para inserir a data e a ação. Isso é extremamente ineficiente, por percorrer várias vezes os mesmos dados, sem necessidade.

Já usando um dicionário, como eu fiz, evita que todo esse trabalho desnecessário seja feito. Eu uso `setdefault(nome, [nome])`, que verifica se a chave referente ao nome já existe. Se não existir, ela é criada, e o valor é setado para uma lista contendo o nome. E como `setdefault` retorna o valor (seja o que foi criado, ou o já existente), basta usá-lo para inserir a nova data e ação - e repare que uso `extend` para inserir dois elementos de uma vez.

No final eu crio uma lista contendo os valores, que é o que você precisa. O dicionário foi apenas uma etapa intermediária que elimina a necessidade de ficar percorrendo várias vezes os dados, o que torna este algoritmo muito mais rápido (pois uma busca para verificar se determinada chave já existe em um dicionário é bem mais rápida do que buscar um elemento em uma lista).

**Claro** que para poucas listas pequenas a diferença será irrisória e provavelmente você nem vai perceber - afinal, [para poucos dados, tudo é rápido](https://blog.codinghorror.com/everything-is-fast-for-small-n/). Mas faça o teste com uma lista maior, e verá a diferença. Para mostrar isso, fiz o teste abaixo, medindo os tempos com o [módulo `timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html):

```py
# lista terá 7 mil elementos
data = []
for i in range(1000):
    data.append([f'Antônio{i}', '01/01/2020', 'Faltou'])
    data.append([f'Antônio{i}', '15/01/2020', 'Remarcou'])
    data.append([f'Fulano{i}', '15/01/2020', 'Faltou'])
    data.append([f'Fulano{i}', '20/01/2020', 'Remarcou'])
    data.append([f'Beltrano{i}', '15/01/2020', 'Faltou'])
    data.append([f'Beltrano{i}', '02/02/2020', 'Faltou'])
    data.append([f'Beltrano{i}', '10/11/2021', 'Compareceu'])

from timeit import timeit

def com_listas():
    resultado = []
    for i in data:
        nomes = [n[0] for n in resultado]
        if i[0] not in nomes:
            resultado.append([i[0], i[1], i[2]])
        else:
            for j in resultado:
                if i[0] == j[0]:
                    j.append(i[1])
                    j.append(i[2])

def com_dicionario():
    resultado = {}
    for nome, dt, acao in data:
        resultado.setdefault(nome, [nome]).extend([dt, acao])
    resultado = list(resultado.values())

# executa 1 vez cada teste
params = { 'number' : 1, 'globals': globals() }
# imprime os tempos em segundos
print(timeit('com_listas()', **params))
print(timeit('com_dicionario()', **params))
```

O tempo pode variar de acordo com o hardware e outros fatores, mas enfim. Na minha máquina o resultado foi (tempos em segundos):

```
0.6838239280041307
0.0019882560009136796
```

Isso quer dizer que a solução usando dicionário foi cerca de 340 vezes mais rápida. Se mudarmos o `for` que insere os elementos para `for i in range(2000):` (ou seja, dobrando o número de elementos), o resultado é:

```
3.7158005590026733
0.004462748001969885
```

Ou seja, agora a solução com dicionário foi cerca de 830 vezes mais rápida. Ao dobrar o número de elementos, a solução com listas demorou 5 vezes mais, enquanto que a solução com dicionário demorou apenas o dobro - isso porque a busca em listas é linear, mas como o processo envolve recriar a lista de nomes e fazer uma busca nela (e depois verificar ela de novo para inserir), o aumento total do algoritmo acaba sendo maior do que o dobro. Já o tempo da solução com dicionários cresce linearmente, pois buscas em dicionários são mais rápidas (também testei com `range(4000)`: a solução com listas fica 21 vezes mais lenta, enquanto que a com dicionário fica só 5).

Como já disse, os tempos variam de acordo com o hardware utilizado. Mas testei em outros ambientes (por exemplo, [no IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/w7ogR9)) e os resultados foram similiares. Isso mostra como faz diferença [escolher a estrutura de dados mais adequada para cada caso](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/163185).

---

#### Sobre a estrutura

Para este caso, não acho que uma lista de listas seja uma boa estrutura. No final você tem uma lista na qual cada uma das sublistas tem o nome seguido dos eventos (data e ação). Fica confuso porque cada elemento da lista significa uma coisa, dependendo da posição (a primeira posição é o nome, depois as datas e ações se alternam).

Em vez disso, poderia ter algo mais organizado, como por exemplo um dicionário contendo os nomes como chaves, e os valores seriam listas contendo o histórico de datas e acões. Algo assim:

```py
{
  "Antônio": [
    ( "01/01/2020", "Faltou" ),
    ( "15/01/2020", "Faltou" ),
    ( "20/01/2020", "Remarcou" )
  ],
  "Pedro": [
    ( "02/02/2020", "Faltou" )
  ],
  "Zeca": [
    ( "10/11/2021", "Compareceu" ),
    ( "15/11/2021", "Faltou" )
  ]
}
```

Ou seja, cada nome é uma chave do dicionário. E seu respectivo valor é uma lista, na qual cada elemento é uma tupla contendo a data e a respectiva ação. Assim fica bem mais organizado do que uma única lista em que cada elemento pode significar uma coisa diferente dependendo da posição.

Para criar a estrutura acima, basta mudar para:

```py
data = [
    ['Antônio', '01/01/2020', 'Faltou'],
    ['Antônio', '15/01/2020', 'Faltou'],
    ['Antônio', '20/01/2020', 'Remarcou'],
    ['Pedro', '02/02/2020', 'Faltou'],
    ['Zeca', '10/11/2021', 'Compareceu'],
    ['Zeca', '15/11/2021', 'Faltou']
]

resultado = {}
for nome, dt, acao in data:
    resultado.setdefault(nome, []).append((dt, acao))
```

A ideia é similar: se o nome não existe no dicionário, cria uma lista vazia (`setdefault(nome, [])`). Senão, `setdefault` retorna a lista já existente. Depois, basta inserir a tupla contendo a data e respectiva ação.

Repare que em `append((dt, acao))` os parênteses parecem redundantes, mas não são. Se eu fizesse apenas `append(dt, acao)`, estaria passando dois argumentos para `append`, e daria erro porque ele só aceita um. Ao colocar o segundo par de parênteses, estou criando uma tupla contendo a data e a ação (ou seja, estou passando apenas um argumento para `append`: a tupla).

E para percorrer os dados, seria algo como:

```py
for nome, acoes in resultado.items():
    print(f'Histórico de {nome}:')
    for data, acao in acoes:
        print(f'- {data} -> {acao}')
```

Saída:

```
Histórico de Antônio:
- 01/01/2020 -> Faltou
- 15/01/2020 -> Faltou
- 20/01/2020 -> Remarcou
Histórico de Pedro:
- 02/02/2020 -> Faltou
Histórico de Zeca:
- 10/11/2021 -> Compareceu
- 15/11/2021 -> Faltou
```

E fazendo testes com `timeit`, a diferença continua brutal: esta solução é muito mais rápida do que o código com listas, com tempos similares ao primeiro código que sugeri acima (mas este eu acho melhor por usar uma estrutura mais adequada e organizada).

Answer (score -2):

Antes de adicionar à lista, podes verificar se esse nome já está na lista. Se não estiver criar uma linha nova, se estiver adicionas a essa linha.

```
resultado = []
for i in data:
    nomes = [n[0] for n in resultado]
    if i[0] not in nomes:
        resultado.append([i[0], i[1], i[2]])
    else:
        for j in resultado:
            if i[0] == j[0]:
                j.append(i[1])
                j.append(i[2])

print(resultado)
```